# AngularJS: directives vs. controllers - What logic to put where?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to angular and try to really learn how to organize my code, so future coworkers will be able to find their way around it quickly.

One rule I know is "If it manipulates the DOM, put it into a directive", which I abide by.

But still there are times where I am unsure where to put my methods, as I can put them into the main app controller, into a controller supplied as the "controller" option within the directive or even within the function that inits the directive (option "link").

With filters and services it's pretty clear to me, but with controllers and directives the line becomes pretty blurry.
I already realized that even with a little app I spread some of the code here and there and it's already confusing, even to myself. So I'd like to get some Tipps on organizing my code better.

So I guess my main question is:
1) Is there a good rule of thumb to know what code to put where?

Or if this is too abstract here are some examples:
2) I have a directive with a template which I only use within my app. Something should happen, when I click on the element. I already know its preferable to use the ng-click directive over binding a click event within the linked function.
But where should I define the method supplied in ng-click?

- A) The main controller of the app.
- B) The "link" function of the directive.
- C) Add a controller to the directive (using the "controller" option) and define it there.

3) Would the answer to 2) be different if I plan to reuse the directive elsewhere?

4) Different Scenario:
I have a Button and when clicked and dragged it should move a completely unrelated Element.
Should I...

- A) Create one directive and influence template & behavior based on a passed attribute?
- B) Create two directives (one for the handle, one for the target Element)
  If so, it again poses the question of where to put the methods to handle the dragging?

Notes:
I am aware the answers might be a little dependent on personal opinion, but I kinda hope there are some "rules" or "right ways to do it" to which I can abide by for future development.
I didn't include any code for conciseness reasons.
Should it be needed for an answer I'd be happy to provide it.

thank you for your time.

Comment: I've always viewed directives the equivalent of jQuery plugins similar to the ones found in jQuery UI. For example, you may have one for a special input types such as date or time. Or maybe you'll have one that creates a country and/or language selector. They should be black boxes that accept parameters and then emit events, trigger callbacks, or update models.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, great question. I think every new-with-angular developer struggles with the differences with all the given components (controller, directive, service, filter etc.).

Let's start with the basic formal definition:

> Directives are markers on a DOM element that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element.

And on the other hand

> Controller is a JavaScript constructor function that is used to augment the Angular Scope

The defined behavior does guide us through some rule-of-thumbs.

**So for your questions above:**

1. In simple words, we user controllers to manage an area (scope) in
   The HTML template with all the great abilities a controller brings
   (two-way-binding, scoped behavior, services injections etc.) And we
   Use directives when we wish to manipulate an existing HTML element or
   Custom out own, in most scenarios - when we think about reusing
   This elements.
2. That depends on the context of what ng-click should do. Lets say you have your customized directive for a numeric input that has a customized designed and behavior as you defined in your directive configuration. And you use it in a form that ng-click suppose to pop a modal with optional values and use it in a different place in the application and ng-click will do something else. In this case the function need to be a scope.fucntion. but let's say both location and every other will do exactly the same, this take the function to the directive scope.
3. Answered above :)
4. Each of your options will do, this where "opinion" takes in and less rule-of-thumbs exists. why? because both ways will work when each has it pros and cons. The rule of thumb I can find in the scenario is that if both elements are part of the directive template, I would expect the 'behavious' (the dragging function) to be part of the directive scope.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! That clears some things up (especially your formal definitions). I'm having trouble understanding your answer for 2 though. Could you further elaborate on that?

Comment: Hey @JanPaepke , what I was trying to abstract is that the way you handle your dilema about the diffrense between a directive to a controller (explained in answer #1) is the way to handle the dilema in question #2. If the directive behaviour will be the same behaviour all over the application, put the behaviour as part of the directive. But if the behviour is diffrent, use the controller scope, define a scope function and use it in the ng-click. Again said - both ways will do the job, but this is the way to do it correct.

Comment: It's still not a 100% clear to me, but I will keep working and get back to this. Maybe I just lack some experience to understand it.

Comment: If you have code snippets to share with question, do it. 
In my exprience (I was terrified of directives at start) you only understand it once you start mess things up

Comment: @BenDiamant but which $scope function in answer #2? The scope of the controller in the state machine, or that in the directive? Are these different? Or related how? What if the directive is active in that state, or not?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there a good rule of thumb to know what code to put where?

Lots of things at play here; and I'm not sure that there is a 'directives vs controllers' battle going on.  They seem different enough to me.  Directives can have their own controllers, if you didn't know.

I view directives as a single, specific, set of encapsulated code including the HTML (View) and JavaScript code (Controller).  I use directives when I want to reuse something as an 'encapsulated' component.

If I just have a bit of JavaScript code that I want to reuse; I'll put in an AngularJS service which I see as just a collection of JavaScript code without any HTML.

> I have a directive with a template which I only use within my app.
>   Something should happen, when I click on the element. I already know
>   its preferable to use the ng-click directive over binding a click
>   event within the linked function. But where should I define the method
>   supplied in ng-click?

I would define the handler as part of the directive's isolated scope; something like this:

```
scope: 
{            
    onButtonClick: '&onButtonClick'
}
```

Define default behavior as part of the Directive's link or controller.

```
link: function ( $scope, element, attrs ) {
  $scope.myDefaultButtonClick = function(){
    // do stuff
  }

        this.onInit = function(){
            if(!$scope.onButtonClick){
                $scope.onButtonClick = $scope.myDefaultButtonClick;
            }
        }
        this.onInit();
}
```

In your JavaScript; you can call the function that is passed in as an argument:

```
$scope.onButtonClick();
```

And you can do the same in your HTML template.

```
<img src="button.png" ng-click="onButtonClick()">
```

> 3) Would the answer to 2) be different if I plan to reuse the
>   directive elsewhere?

If I do not plan for reuse; I would probably not use a directive.

```
I have a Button and when clicked and dragged it should move a completely unrelated Element.
Should I...

    A) Create one directive and influence template & behavior based on a passed attribute?
    B) Create two directives (one for the handle, one for the target Element)
    If so, it again poses the question of where to put the methods to handle the dragging?
```

I would chose item A probably; passing in the element that needs to be manipulated as an argument to the directive.  However, it depends how much I care about re usability of this piece of functionality.

Everything I say should be considered subjective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I might have been too unclear in my question. I am aware that directives can have their own controller, but this is part of my problem. How do I decide which methods to define where? In your example for 2) You defined it in the link function. But it could also be in the app controller or the directives personal controller. How do I decide?

Comment: @JanPaepke In my example; I defined a **DEFAULT** method in the link [it could also have been in the directive's controller].  However, it could easily be replaced with any function you desire using the API.  When creating a directive; I put all the directive-specific code inside the directive.  But, it is really a judgement call based on what you're trying to do.